# how to Print Source code of a page using curl nad simple_html_dom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Hi i am trying to print a source code of HTML page but it is not working , can someone please help.

Here is the code :

```
$curl->get('https://google.com');
$response = $curl->getRawResponse();
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);
$source = stream_get_contents($html);
echo $source;
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: `$html` is not a stream.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple HTML DOM object is not a stream, you can't use it as the argument to `stream_get_contents()`.

The opposite of the `load()` method is `save()`. It returns the contents of the object as a string, or writes it to a file if given a filename argument. So you should use:

```
$source = $html->save();
```